# Mongodb $or evaluation

Tags: mongodb

In javascript

`const a = func1() || func2()`

if `func1()` return true, `func2()` is skipped (won't be called)

Does this hold true in mongodb $or as well?

`db.collection('something').find( { $or: [ { quantity: { $lt: 20 } }, { price: { $gt: 100 } } ] } )`

Will mongodb stops evaluating price if the quantity is < 20?

Comment: That's 2 different concept. The `||` is short-circuit evaluation expression. While `$or` is a logical disjunction. For your query, mongo will every document that quantity is either < 20 OR > 100. Example of matched documents: `[ { quantity: 18 }, { quantity: 19 } , { quantity: 101 }  ]`

Comment: No it wont stop if the price quantity is less than 20 because its $or,if any one of the condition is true it will provide u the result

Answer (score 2):

The $or takes a list, in which the order matters.

This is referred to as "short circuit" evaluation, where if the first condition does not match then is the next condition tested and so on.

The query:

```
db.somecollection.find( { $or: [ { quantity: { $lt: 20 } }, { price: { $gt: 100 } } ] } )
```

This query will select all documents in the *somecollection* where the quantity field value is less than 20.

If this condition does not gets satisfied, the the next condition is tested i.e if the price field value greater than 100.

[Source](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/or/)

Comment: I understand its function. My question is whether mongodb evaluates the `{ price: { $gt: 100 } }` if the `{ quantity: { $lt: 20 } }` returns true using the `$or` operator, just out of curiosity.

Comment: Edited the post. You may refer now.